# Extract arithmetic operation information from C++ code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am facing a problem of extracting arithmetic operation information from C++ source code. For example, I want to parse a C++ code such that I can find out the the line numbers for all the codes that conduct arithmetic operations as well as the name of the variables or literals involved in the operation and the corresponding operation type. I am interested in built-in types such as int and double as well as user-defined classes where arithmetic operators such as operator+, operator* are overloaded.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Edit: I was hoping that some compilers might generate some intermediate results that I can utilize to achieve this goal. I did some search and it seems that libclang can generate some useful intermediate results, but I just want to get some suggestions before I spend too much time on digging into it.

Comment: So you want to account for all arithmetic operation in the *source code* as written, regardless of whether such operations may be eliminated or modified in generated machine code during code optimizations, e.g. through CSE or strength reduction?

Comment: Are you really trying to parse `h and cpp` files yourself?? You should start reading Dragon's (Aho et al. ) book.

Comment: The only way to parse C++ code is by using a C++ compiler. C++ is the most complicated general-purpose programming language in use today, and the only kind of a program in the world that knows how to parse C++ code is a C++ compiler. Looks like what you need to do is write your own C++ compiler, which should only take a few years. Just a few.

Comment: @njuffa yes I want to extract the information before optimization.

Comment: You might investigate for Clang and LLVM. IMHO, Clang is one of the most uptodate C++ compilers. The LLVM provides an API where you can inspect (and even modify) intermediate results like e.g. the Abstract Syntax Tree. This is the most promising place to find what you want.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Come on, do not exaggerate. Writing a compiler is not needed. A parser would be sufficient. That should be doable in ...  a few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able use clang-query to do it. Getting the queries just right is a bit tricky, but the [llvm ast matcher docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) are quite useful providing examples for every matcher. It also prints line/col numbers for the matched results.

Example code:

```
struct complex { float r, i; };

int operator*(int a, complex b)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    complex b;
    return (a * a) + (a * b);
}
```

Example query that returns math expressions which have been overloaded:

> match cxxOperatorCallExpr(anyOf(hasOverloadedOperatorName("-"),
>   hasOverloadedOperatorName("+"), hasOverloadedOperatorName("*"),
>   hasOverloadedOperatorName("/")))

Output:

> ```
>    return (a * a) + (a * b);
>
>                      ^~~~~
> ```